# Include 1 previous and 1 next elements in a paged result set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, kaminari

I have this:

```
  source = MyModel.all.some_filter(some_condition).order("condition123 ASC")   # 1
  res1 = source.page(params[:page]).per(PAGE_SIZE)                         # 2
```

I also want to retrieve 2 more items from `source` that "surround" `res1` - its neighbors :

```
  neighbour1 = 
    if params[:page] > 1
      source.page(params[:page] - 1).per(1).order("condition123 DESC") 
    else
      nil
    end

   neighbour2 = 
     unless last_page(source)
       source.page(params[:page] + 1).per(1) 
     else
       nil
     end
```

and merge the results all together:

```
full_result = neighbour1 + res1 + neighbour2
```

First off all, is there any way to make it more effective?

And how do I merge the results if `neighbour1` or `neighbour2` are nil? If do this:

```
    if params[:page] > 1
     source += source.page(params[:page] - 1).per(1).order("condition123 DESC") 
    end
```

then source will be converted to Array and I won't be able to use page anymore. I know I could do this via `Kaminary.page` but I prefer just to get source not to convert itself to array and remain `MyModel::ActiveRecord_Relation`